# MFC - Scanning my code for any leftover timers, events, threads etc when the DLL unloads

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, dll, mfc

I have an MFC based DLL.

I have a phenomena that the main application which loads my DLL crashes upon exiting.

The application developer suspects it relates to my DLL and wants me to scan my code for any leftover timers, events, threads etc. when the DLL unloads.

What are the best ways I can approch this task?

I work on VS2008.

Best regards,Tal

Answer (score 2):

The question of itself tells me that there is a high probability your college is wrong. Most developer know about that kind of resources.
But anyway, search for:

1. SetTimer -> There should be a KillTimer
2. AfxBeginThread -> you should wait on thread end before you let anyone unint your dll
3. CreateThread -> same as AfxBeginThread
4. Look where you set CALLBACKs in Win32 or Afx functions. You have to make sure that you won't be "called back" after DLL is closed.
5. Non modal dialogs like toolboxes are sometimes also a problem. The should be ended cleanly.
6. If you have control of the interface the DLL uses, introduce a dedicated uninit function/method. Make sure you throw an exception if anyone accesses any resources after the call of that uninit. If there is already something like a uninit or close command, use that.
7. Write your own DllTestProgramm. Where you test your DLL with the same circumstances as the developer does.

After checkmark those points go back to the developer, tell him "it works in my program" he will love that.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the free Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition or a VS 2013 Trial Version. It has got a built in code analyzer capable of pointing out problems with your code.